Spectrum of normal operator with positive real part
Suppose $H$ is a complex Hiblert space and $A:H\to H$ is a normal operator. I want to show that
$$Re(\lambda) \geq 0 \text{ for all $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$} \iff Re(<x,Ax>) \geq 0 \text{ for all $x\in H$}$$
where $Re$ refer to the real part of a complex number and $\sigma(A)$ denotes the specturm of $A$.
I know that normal operator has only point spectrum and continuous specturm, and I know how to show $\impliedby$ for $\lambda$ being point spectrum. But I don't know how to do the remaining part. Any hint will be appreciated.

Use spectral theorem to show that $\langle x, Ax\rangle$ for unit vector $x$ is always in the closed convex hall of $\sigma(A)$, from which the result is quite immediate.

Let me expand my comment into an answer: by continuous functional calculus (and essentially following the proof of the spectral theorem), for any unit vector $x \in H$, we have the following linear functional on $C(\sigma(A))$:
$$C(\sigma(A)) \ni f \mapsto \langle x, f(A)x \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$$
The said linear functional is clearly positive, and sends $1$ to $1$, so by Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem, there is a Radon probability measure $\mu_x$ on $\sigma(A)$ s.t.,
$$\langle x, f(A)x \rangle = \int_{\sigma(A)} f(t) \, d\mu_x(t)$$
In particular, applying this to the inclusion function $f: \sigma(A) \to \mathbb{C}$, we have,
$$\langle x, Ax \rangle = \int_{\sigma(A)} t \, d\mu_x(t)$$
As $\mu_x$ is a probability measure, it follows that $\langle x, Ax \rangle \in \overline{\text{co}}(\sigma(A))$, where $\overline{\text{co}}$ indicates the closed convex hull. As $\sigma(A) \subset \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$ and the latter set is closed and convex, $\overline{\text{co}}(\sigma(A))$ is a subset of the latter set as well. That is to say, for any unit vector $x \in H$,
$$\text{Re}(\langle x, Ax \rangle) \geq 0$$
The result for general $x \in H$ now follows from rescaling.
